# Are there tools for branch-level test coverage tracking for Pharo/Squeak?

Tags: testing, code-coverage, smalltalk, squeak, pharo

I am looking for something that could visualize code coverage on the branch/statement level.

My understanding is that the test coverage tool provide by the test runner in Pharo and Squeak only tell me which methods haven't been called.

I also had a look at Hapao. First I found that the [linked image](http://objectprofile.com/pier/Products/Hapao/Download) was rather old, but even after loading the latest version into a fresh image, I still had the feeling that it provides me with a lot information that is not immediately helpful to answer my questions.

From the C world, I am used to things like gcov and [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php), where I can see immediately which branches haven't been covered.

Is there something similar available in the Pharo or Squeak universe?
Reading a recent thread on the [Pharo mailing list](http://forum.world.st/Proposal-coverage-tests-td4407271.html) gives me the impression: 'not yet'?

Comment: Sadly it's been on my to-do list for ages, not on my "oh here it is" list.

Answer (score 2):

I know there is branch level code coverage in VisualWorks extensions (found in Cincom public store)

- SUnitToo(verage)
  http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/publicRepository/SUnitToo(verage).html
- SUnitToo(lsoverage)
  similar address (I'm SO noob, and can't post more than 2 links)
- See this blog too http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/userblogs/mls/blogView?entry=3346628542

I don't know the license, nor if it would be easily portable though...

Answer (score 2):

Stefan Reichhart implements and describes various cool tools to improve test quality in his [master thesis](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/masters/Reic07b.pdf). The tool [Christo](http://www.squeaksource.com/Coverage.html) (described in Appendix B) provided sub-method level test-coverage and visualized coverage in the browsers. Unfortunately the code is unlikely to work in more recent Squeak/Pharo images, as it builds on top of libraries that got lost over the years (NewCompiler and ByteSurgeon).